# All GET methods in API gateway REST API returns 403 and HTML content

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I've set up an API gateway with an OpenAPI spec and Lambda integration via CloudFormation. It's deployed correctly and all methods and resources are displayed etc.
If I call one of my POST, PATCH or DELETE methods (or even OPTIONS!), they successfully reach my lambda function and returns as expected.
However, as soon as I call one of my endpoints using a GET or HEAD method - either a GET endpoint that exists, or a non-existing GET method such as /foobar, all I get is a HTTP 403 with *HTML* content instead of JSON:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>403 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
Bad request.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
<BR clear="all">
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: ju-yNp9QlyjqrAFHC3xR9DkO0N9DaPK2BcVQlpeswPMEerwErwdDUw==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

The headers only include `X-Cache: Error from Cloudfront`, none of the regular API gateway headers are there, such as `x-amzn-ErrorType`. I believe the request doesn't even reach my API gateway.

I'm calling my `xxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` URL, so CloudFront is not manually put in front, but I guess API gateway itself uses CloudFront. Is caching for some reason enabled for my GET endpoints? In my API gateway stage params, "API cache" is disabled, and I cannot find anything else remotely related to CloudFront or caching.

My API and its integration looks like this:

```
  /mypath:
    get:
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        type: aws_proxy
        passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
        httpMethod: POST
        uri: arn:aws:apigateway:eu-west-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxx:function:${stageVariables.LambdaName}/invocations
        requestParameters: {}
        responses:
          '200':
            statusCode: '200'
          '400':
            statusCode: '400'
```

This kind of integration works for all non-GET requests, but causes this strange error for all GET requests.
I have DEFAULT_4XX responses in place, and that works too for all other methods, such as POST /something-non-existing - that renders my custom response fine. I have no HTML content configured anywhere, so why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this happens only when I try to do a GET with a request body. I was using Postman and by accident I had kept my request body from a previous POST request. When I remove the body, the GET requests work.

I haven't found any way to prevent this strange handling of "body not permitted with GET or HEAD".